# How to handle redirects with the safebrowsing - api?

Tags: php, google-api, safe-browsing-api

I have a website that allows others to share urls. To make sure noone enters "evil" sites I use the google safebrowsing api:

```
 $url = 'https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key='.$key;
    $data = array(
        'client' => array('clientId'=> $clientId, 'clientVersion'=>'0.1'),
        'threatInfo' => array(
            'threatTypes'=>array('MALWARE', 'SOCIAL_ENGINEERING','UNWANTED_SOFTWARE'),
            'platformTypes'=> array('ANY_PLATFORM','ALL_PLATFORMS', 'ANDROID','WINDOWS','IOS','OSX','LINUX'),
            'threatEntryTypes'=> array('URL'),
            'threatEntries' => array('url'=>$tsturl)
        ),
    );
    $data_json=json_encode($data);
    $ch=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response  = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

**This works** as designed. So if I add a phishing site like `thisisevil.com` the api-call returns a warning.

But if someone uses an url shortener like `tny.sh/abcefg` which then redirects to `thisisevil.com` the safebrowsing-api does *not* show me there is a threat.

Is there a way to tell the secure browsing api to follow redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always make a request to the URL you want to test and see if it redirects somewhere, and if so pass that redirected URL to the safebrowsing API.

But ultimately you can only make it harder, if someone wants to redirect to a malicious  URL, they will. Blacklists are at best only partially effective.